# Meta-package dependency chains

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm looking to strip my system down to the bare essentials it needs to be a ".. well rather pretty.." place to get some dev work done. I'm digging through the `~# dpkg --list` and am noticing a fistful of oddly named printer drivers for printers I will never use. Then there's the drivers for protocols for systems that as my research yields, were strictly in use in academia, and enterprise like, the late 80's... Basically there are a lot of packages, that I'm confident I'm not going to use `cups` and `samba` at the top of my list.

Is there a tried and true method, more sophisticated than removing the Meta-Packages, purging a package, and dropping to one of the `ctrl+alt+f#` terminals to reinstall it if I break something?

I've had incredible boot and shutdown time decreases, disabling unnecessary services daemon from auto starting, (ModemManager - good-bye), hoping I can get a boost in general file system performance from limiting the number of packages, and files that need to be indexed. I'm running an old system.

Any solid methodology that beats my go to, trial and error approach to gutting the bloatware, would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you are looking to gut bloatware, why start with Ubuntu? I would suggest starting with something like Arch and add the things you need/want.

Comment: The only thing you will gain some speed from is disabling services. Removing packages is not going to make a lot of room but will cost a lot of time.  And yes, Ubuntu is meant as a desktop with on-line access and lots of features. What you are asking for sounds like Arch.

Comment: No. There isn't. If there are any, those are in individual systems achieved through trial and error and I fear, customizing your base ubuntu that extent may make it a non-ubuntu

Comment: I do most of my dev on a Mac for work, but prefer the gnome/unity layout. I guess I was maybe just trying to pare it down a minimal server-install with a GUI. I like Ubuntu, and it's the platform at work, so I gotta stay into it. it's good to know that the services are the main hang up though. Thanks

Comment: Start from `ubuntu-minimal`, then install only what you need.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not shy away from doing a fresh installation, you could install Ubuntu Server and choosing only the minimal installation. After that, only install packages (i.e. a desktop environment) using:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends package-name
```

The `--no-installation-recommends` flag installs packages with only the main dependencies needed but without the recommended.

---

**EDIT:**

If you do not want to write `--no-installation-recommends` every time you install a package, you can configure the **apt-get** default behavior to do this automatically by adding the following line to your **/etc/apt/apt.conf** file:

```
APT::Install-Recommends "false";
```

To undo this, either simply delete the edited line or comment it out by adding two `//` at the beginning of the line.

```
//APT::Install-Recommends "false";
```

See `man apt.conf` for more details.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a shot. If this accomplishes what I'm going for I'll rephrase the question's request for a methodology to strip the bloatware to something that fits this better but looks for the same effect. Does     `--no-install-recommends` work with `apt-get remove` or `purge` too?

Comment: In `man apt-get` it reads:  --no-install-recommends  Do not consider recommended packages as a dependency for installing.  So it only affects `apt-get intall`.